# Can you configure wildfly 10 application server with different jdk?

Tags: java, wildfly

I have the following situation:

On the wildfly n applications are deployed, but now I have to deploy another application that uses 32-bit architecture, due to the project and the connection to a database with visual fox pro, so I need to deploy this application which runs a jdk of 32 bits The other applications will continue with 64-bit jdk. Is this possible?.

Comment: Are you using standalone or domain mode?

Comment: I am using domain mode.

Comment: Depending on your setup then you should be able to define a different JVM for that specific server.